# Cannot get subprocess output in Django view

Tags: python, django, tensorflow, subprocess

I want to emulate command line call of my script (TensorFlow neaural chatbot model) in Django view and get output from console to variable.

When i do manually in terminal of my server:

```
python3 var/www/engine/chatbot/udc_predict.py --model_dir=var/www/engine/chatbot/runs/1486057482/
```

the output is good and printed out.

So in my Django view i do:

```
        import subprocess
        answer = subprocess.check_output(['python3', 'var/www/engine/chatbot/udc_predict.py','--model_dir=var/www/engine/chatbot/runs/1486057482/'], shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, timeout=None)
        print('answer', answer)
```

And `answer` variable is printed as `b''` in Apache error log.

I cannot figure out what's wrong in my call.

Comment: Try passing `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` to the `subprocess.check_output()` call

Comment: @ZdaR your comment shifted me to solve

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use .communicate() and PIPE:

```
        from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
        proc = Popen(
            "python3 var/www/engine/chatbot/udc_predict.py --model_dir=var/www/engine/chatbot/runs/1486057482/",
            shell=True,
            stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE
        )
        proc.wait()    
        res = proc.communicate() 
        if proc.returncode:
            print(res[1])
        print('result:', res[0])
        answer = res[0]
```